# Passing values to a method in a different class - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, parameters

I have two classes: `Drawing` and `Game`. In `Drawing` there is a class called `redraw`, which appears as follows:

`- (void) redraw:(int)x:(int)y {`

Now, there are many other methods in `Drawing` which to not require values to be passed to it, and I can even call them from `Game` using the following code: `[drawing callSomeMethod];`.

(By the way, `drawing` is created in `Game.m`, like this: `Drawing *drawing`.

I would have assumed that in the `redraw` method above, to call that from `Game` all i'd have to do it write: `[drawing someMethod(val1, val2)];`, but I keep getting the following error: `No visible @interface for 'Drawing' declares the selector 'redraw:'"`

How can I pass val1 and val2 (defined in `Game.m`) to a method in `Drawing.m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure this method is declared in Drawing.h

```
- (void) redraw:(int)x:(int)y;
```

Once that's done, this will work:

```
Drawing *drawing = [[Drawing alloc] init];
[drawing redraw:3:5]; // where 3 and 5 are whatever x and y values you choose.
```

Comment: Ah. I was getting myself mixed up with java syntax. someMethod(val1, val2) doesn't work, it's someMethod:val1:val2, as you said. Thanks